# How to pass dynamic values as field name for an array collection in flex 3

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript, flex3

```
 public function Adddynamic_values(val:String):void
        {
            for(var i:int=0;i<Gridvaltest.length;i++)
            {
                Gridvaltest.setItemAt({label:"A",number:"1",val:val},i);
            }

        }
```

This is my code. Now i want  to know how to add dynamic value as field name for an array collection. Is it possible or any other way to do like this?

If we are passing the "val" value like mentioned above example

it cosidered as string  ie ( I have attached little bit of code for better understand)

```
    [1] (Object)#4
    label = "A"
    number = "1"
    val = "233.5"
```

I got this was the output. But i want like this ( if the dynamic value will be "val" = 255 )

```
   [1] (Object)#4
    label = "A"
    number = "1"
    255 = "233.5"
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your parameter val into something other than val like ""value".

```
public function Adddynamic_values(value:String):void
{
    for(var i:int=0;i<Gridvaltest.length;i++)
    {
        Gridvaltest.setItemAt({label:"A",number:"1",val:value},i);
    }
}
```

This should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks for your ideas. But i want field name and field value both will be dynamic like [1] (Object)#4
    label = "A"
    number = "1"
    value = value  ie ( 255 = 255 )

Comment: Otherwise , how to get dynamic added colums of datagrid dataprovider? I want to get that dataprovider as array collection to process further and insert into database.